# How to remove dot (.) character in email address using regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I have an email address like `n.abc@abc-xyz.de` and I came up with a simple pattern like :

```
String reglarEx="^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$"
```

My requirement is to not allow the `dot(.)` operator before the `@` sign or the entire email contain only one dot operator.

Comment: here it works https://regex101.com/r/lJ3aS8/1

Comment: Unfortunatelly real email addresses are not as simple as your regular expression checks them (e.g. `"very.unusual.@.unusual.com"@example.com` is a valid email address). So no matter how hard you try you still will get the case where your regular expression fails to check whether email address is valid or not.

Comment: i konw sim.but my reqirement is e-mail address do not contain 2 or more than dot operator.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this regex:

```
String reglarEx = "^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@([A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\\.)+[A-Za-z0-9]([A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$";
```

Or shortened:

```
String reglarEx = "^[\\w!#$%&'*+/=?^`{|}~-]+@(\\p{Alnum}(\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Alnum})?\\.)+\\p{Alnum}(\\p{Alnum}*\\p{Alnum})$";
```

Although **entire email contain only one dot operator** doesn't seem right requirement since email can be `name@google.co.uk` also.

Comment: Isn't there shortcut for `[A-Za-z0-9]`? Regexes like this are incredible unreadable.

Comment: @anubhva his requirement is email not contain dot operator before @ sign.

Comment: @VishalRathod: Yes that's what this regex does. [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/zL0zG8/1)

Comment: @kajacx: check updated regex for shortcut of `[A-Za-z0-9]`

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.